# Not getting fields and their values which are ManyToManyField type

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model named Persona:

```
class Persona(models.model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    pages_visited = models.ManyToManyField(Page)
    items_searched = models.ManyToManyField(ItemsSearched)
    visits = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    connect = models.CharField(max_length=True,null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have an object for this model:

```
<QuerySet [<Persona: aman>]>
```

Now when i am trying to get the values of all fields for this object i can see all fields and their corresponding values except fields which are ManyToManyField type.

I get the following result when i execute this : Persona.objects.filter(name='aman').values()

```
<QuerySet [{'visits': None, 'image_id': 3, 'name': 'aman', 'connect': 'call'}]>
```

I cannot see 'items_searched' and 'pages_visited' fields and their corresponding values though when i log into admin i can see them.

These are the images which show you my execution:

**Command Prompt**
[image]

**Admin Panel**
[image]

Comment: I think pages_visited and items_searched should show with their related Id's. Do you see those in your response ?

Comment: I can see the values in admin panel. I have uploaded images. Please check it and help me out. @Shakil

Answer (score 0):

To access m2m filed in django there is **.all()** keyword refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

```
p1 = Persona.objects.filter(name='aman')
p1_m2m = p1.pages_visited.all()
```

which will give the result you wanted

Comment: Sir I want to know why can't i see M2M fields and their values. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: hi @AshokKumar just go through this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField you will get know why you can't see m2m fields

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `Inlines`.

In your admin file, add

```
from .models import Page # Edit this import according to your project structure

class PagesVisitedInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page

class PersonaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    [...] # admin code goes here
    inlines = [PagesVisitedInline, ]
```

You could use `StackedInline` aswell if you prefer, read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).